# angular add text with image at once

Tags: angular

I have a page with articles on the site. And I want to add the possibility to add an article through UI. So, no problem with adding text or title with set CSS. But how to implement if images should be shown in some places inside the article and I don't know where. Articles are saved in DB and get through API.

How to implement it?
Have an idea that user should upload images separately first. But what to do then?
And also is there is a way to set the different color of separate parts of text inside an article?
Any thoughts or help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar problem (email editor). We user quill editor. `https://quilljs.com/`. This took care of most of the html content editing. As for picture we also save it in db and then created the REST service that was invoked  like that /api/img/XXXXXXX where XXXXXXX was image id. And it would return byte[].

When in html we wrote
`<img src="/api/img/XXXXXXX" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">`

the image was properly displayed on the page.

Comment: thank you for your response. It is clear about images. But how to insert it from ui in a definite part of text?

Comment: This was a major selling point for the quill. It abstract that functionality away. You have a valid html article that has <img> tag exactly where the author put it.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to identify the areas where you need the images in the article and create templates as per your requirement, one with the image and one without the image.
Wherever you need the article with image use template with image and vice-versa.
Try to check with image required field.
Best way to create an awesome template is using material-angular.

Comment: thank you for an answer. I will think about it. The thing is that I have no idea how many images user will want to add to the article

Comment: I've investigating this editor.this is definetely what I need. Thank you much

Comment: I have a better option, create a template for image and add images dynamically with `createElement` and iterate the `createElement` depending upon the no of images.

Comment: I think this will solve your problem. **Let me know if it is useful.** In this case, there is no need for creating multiple templates.

Comment: thank you for response.I have not tried createElement, because quil does definitely what I need. But I am interested anoue your approach and will study it later